# How to use value (eg: insert to mysql) from slide range after press ok button?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

How to use value (eg: insert to mysql) from slide range after press ok button ?

after press submit insert to mysql (in php tag not script)

http://jsfiddle.net/5Kvk5/1/

```
$(function() {
    var minPriceInRupees = 0;
    var maxPriceInRupees = 500;
    var currentMinValue = 33;
    var currentMaxValue = 333;

    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: minPriceInRupees,
        max: maxPriceInRupees,
        values: [ currentMinValue, currentMaxValue ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
            currentMinValue = ui.values[ 0 ];
            currentMaxValue = ui.values[ 1 ];
        }
    });

    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
" - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/5Kvk5/2/

you need the on click event and just get the values of your slider:

```
$(":submit").on("click", function(){
   var values = $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "option", "values" );
    // do all your fancy stuff here
    // the slider values are available via values[0] and values[1]
    // as proof of concept, we write them into the console using the following line
    console.log(values[0], values[1]);
});
```

to pass it to a php script i would do something like that:

```
$.post( "meServerSide.php", { minVal: values[0], maxVal: values[1]});
```

your php then can access it with

```
$_POST["minVal"];
$_POST["maxVal"];
```

Comment: i want to use in php tag , how can i do ?

Comment: use an ajax call to post the values[0] and values[1] to your php

Comment: EG: `<?PHP echo values[0]; ?>`

Comment: see the updated answer ... but it would be easier to use khaki's approach, since i assume, that you need the whole form data after your submit, and not only the slider values...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are able to obtain the values of the slider. You now need them to be included in the form.

```
currentMinValue = ui.values[0];
currentMaxValue = ui.values[1];
```

In your form, you must add the fields for the min and max values.

```
<input type="text" id="minValue" name="minValue" readonly />
<input type="text" id="maxValue" name="maxValue" readonly />
```

Note, the `name` attribute in the input elements.

In your PHP code, you can now obtain the data like this

```
<?php echo $_POST['minValue']; ?>
<?php echo $_POST['maxValue']; ?>
```

Then in your SQL statement, it could be something like this.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `table_name` (`field`) VALUES (`$_POST[minValue]`)";
```

The code examples here are crude but this is to give you an idea. So please read about [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) in PHP to prevent injection attacks.

[**See JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5Kvk5/4/)